# Symbolic statement that represents the circuit

Tags: education

im over here a tad bit confused. Ive been asked to write a symbolic statement that represents the circuit in this picture.

[Circut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2E4c.png)

Problem is I don't understand how. I've searched this on google and nothing. Any tips on how to solve this would be great!

Comment: You do not need to google this. Just look at your textbook. That would help you a lot.

Comment: I would ask for more information from the person who asked you to write this statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Every symbolic statement can be represented by a circuit and vice versa. Given a circuit sketch, try imagining current flowing through it from left to right. Whenever current **has** to reach a conjunction of statements then $ \land (\land_ip_i)$, whereas if the circuit lines split and reaching a certain conjunction is **optional**, then $\lor(\land_i p_i). $